# Lee, Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, Change of Coordinates

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

In all versions of John M. Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*, he claims that

$$\left(\psi\circ\varphi^{-1}\right)_*\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial
x^i}\right|_{\varphi\left(p\right)}=\left.\frac{\partial\tilde
x^j}{\partial
x^i}\left(\varphi\left(p\right)\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial\tilde
x^j}\right|_{\psi\left(p\right)},$$

where $\left(U,\varphi\right)=\left(U,\left(x^i\right)\right)$ and $\left(V,\psi\right)=\left(V,\left(\tilde x^i\right)\right)$ are smooth charts of some smooth manifold such that $p\in U\cap V$.

However, this is what I computed:

$$\begin{align}\left(\psi\circ\varphi^{-1}\right)_*\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right|_{\varphi\left(p\right)}&=\psi_*\left(\left(\varphi^{-1}\right)_*\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right|_{\varphi\left(p\right)}\right)\\&=\psi_*\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right|_p\\&=\left.\frac{\partial\tilde x^j}{\partial x^i}\left(\color{red}{p}\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial\tilde x^j}\right|_{\psi\left(p\right)}.\end{align}$$

I highlighted my difference in red. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Doesn't $\partial \tilde x^j/\partial x^i$ need to be evaluated in the $x^i$ coordinate system? Just like $\mathrm dy/\mathrm dx$ would, usually, be evaluated at $x=1$. Wouldn't the derivatives of $\phi$ and $\psi$ be the ones to be evaluated at $p$?

Comment: @FlybyNight, $(x^i)$ and $(\tilde x^i)$ are just the component functions of $\varphi$ and $\psi$, respectively. That is, $\varphi(x)=(x^1(x),...,x^n(x))$ and $\psi(x)=(\tilde x^1(x),...,\tilde x^n(x))$, assuming the manifold is $n$-dimensional. So, $x^i:U\to\mathbb R$ and $\tilde x^i:V\to\mathbb R$ for each $i$, which makes me think that my computation might be correct.

Comment: What is $\left. \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} \right|_{\varphi(p)}$ ? Is this an element of $T \mathbb{R}^m |_{\varphi(p)}$ ?

Comment: Think about what derivatives mean. $\mathrm ds/\mathrm dt$ tells you how $s$ changes with respect to $t$. Similarly, $\partial \tilde x^j/\partial x^i$ tells you how $\tilde x^j$ changes as we change $x^i$. It makes sense that $x^i$ is the independent variable.

Comment: @Gustavo, that is correct. Lee denotes it as $T_{\varphi(p)}(\mathbb R^m)$, and it is a basis element.

Comment: @FlybyNight, Lee likes to abuse the notation a lot, and he concedes this several times in his book. I think that the $x^i$'s in this case are the preimages of the coordinates of $\mathbb R^n$ under $\varphi$, which would still imply that $\tilde x^i:U\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: I should also mention that Lee likes to use Einstein's summation convention. I feel like this question is too idiosyncratic, but hopefully someone will bear with me.

Comment: It seems that the solution is obvious. The author likes to abuse notation and this causes you to doubt yourself. You have to spend time on a forum to decide if you're right or if the author is right. You need to stop reading this book and get another one. This level of Maths is hard enough with a good teacher.

Comment: The notation is a bit confusing. At the first LHS this basis element is related to the i-th coordinate function of the inclusion map, which is the standard chart of $\mathbb{R}^m$, and not to the chart $\varphi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please allow me to introduce another notation. Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with dimension $ \ m \in \mathbb{N}^*$, $U$ and $V$ be open sets, $p \in U \cap V$, $x:U \to \mathbb{R}^m \ $ and $ \ y:V \to \mathbb{R}^m \ $ be charts at $p$ and $ \ i: im(x) \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m \ $ and $ \ j: im(y) \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^m \ $ be the inclusion maps. As usual, we denote the coordinate maps $ \ x = (x^1,...,x^m)$, $y= (y^1,...,y^m)$, $i = (i^1,...,i^m) \ $ and $ \ j = (j^1,...,j^m)$. So, for all $ \ \mu \in \{ 1,...,m \}$, the maps $ \ i^{\mu}: im(x) \to \mathbb{R} \ $ and $ \ j^{\mu}: im(y) \to \mathbb{R} \ $ are just restrictions of the projection onto the $\mu$-th coordinate.

Treating tangent vectors as derivations acting on germs, first note that, $\forall h \in C^{\infty} \big( x(p) \big)$, we have
\begin{align*} \displaystyle \left\{ \Big[ d(x^{-1})|_{x(p)} \Big] \left( \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial i^{\mu}} \right|_{x(p)} \right) \right\}(h) & = \left[ \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial i^{\mu}} \right|_{x(p)} \right] (h \circ x^{-1}) = \\ & = [\partial_{\mu} (h \circ x^{-1} \circ i^{-1})] \Big(i \big( x(p) \big) \Big) = \\ & = [\partial_{\mu} (h \circ x^{-1})] \big( x(p) \big) = \\ & = \left( \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}} \right|_{p} \right) (h) \ \ .
\end{align*}
Then, $\forall \mu \in \{ 1,...,m \}$, we have $$\displaystyle \Big[ d(x^{-1})|_{x(p)} \Big] \left( \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial i^{\mu}} \right|_{x(p)} \right) = \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}} \right|_{p} \ \ . $$ By the chain rule, $\forall \mu \in \{ 1,...,m \}$, we conclude that
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle \big[ d(y \circ x^{-1})|_{x(p)} \big] \left( \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial i^{\mu}} \right|_{x(p)} \right) & = \Big[ dy|_{x^{-1} (x(p))} \circ d(x^{-1})|_{x(p)} \Big] \left( \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial i^{\mu}} \right|_{x(p)} \right) = \\ & = (dy|_p) \left( \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}} \right|_{p} \right) = \\ & = \sum_{\nu = 1}^{m} \left[ \left( \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}} \right|_{p} \right) (j^{\nu} \circ y) \right] \cdot \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial j^{\nu}} \right|_{y(p)} = \\ & = \sum_{\nu = 1}^{m} \left[ \left( \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}} \right|_{p} \right) (y^{\nu}) \right] \cdot \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial j^{\nu}} \right|_{y(p)} = \\ & = \sum_{\nu = 1}^{m} \frac{\partial y^{\nu}}{\partial x^{\mu}} (p) \cdot \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial j^{\nu}} \right|_{y(p)} \ \ .
\end{align*}

Or we can compute, $\forall \mu \in \{ 1,...,m \}$,
\begin{align*}
\displaystyle \big[ d(y \circ x^{-1})|_{x(p)} \big] \left( \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial i^{\mu}} \right|_{x(p)} \right) & = \sum_{\nu = 1}^{m} \left[ \left( \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial x^{\mu}} \right|_{p} \right) (y^{\nu}) \right] \cdot \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial j^{\nu}} \right|_{y(p)} = \\ & = \sum_{\nu = 1}^{m} [\partial_{\mu} (y^{\nu} \circ x^{-1})] \big( x(p) \big) \cdot \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial j^{\nu}} \right|_{y(p)} = \\ & = \sum_{\nu = 1}^{m} [\partial_{\mu} (y^{\nu} \circ x^{-1} \circ i^{-1})] \Big( i \big( x(p) \big) \Big) \cdot \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial j^{\nu}} \right|_{y(p)} = \\ & = \sum_{\nu = 1}^{m} \left\{ \left[ \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial i^{\mu}} \right|_{x(p)} \right] (y^{\nu} \circ x^{-1}) \right\} \cdot \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial j^{\nu}} \right|_{y(p)} = \\ & = \sum_{\nu = 1}^{m} \left[ \frac{\partial (y^{\nu} \circ x^{-1})}{\partial i^{\mu}} \right] \big( x(p) \big) \cdot \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial j^{\nu}} \right|_{y(p)} \ \ .
\end{align*}

Using that, $\forall \nu \in \{ 1,...,m \}$, $$y^{\nu} \circ x^{-1} = j^{\nu} \circ y \circ x^{-1} = (y \circ x^{-1})^{\nu}$$ is the $\nu$-th coordinate function of the map $y \circ x^{-1}$, we have the desired equality.

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation makes it all crystal clear!

Answer (score 3):

I think that I discovered the problem: he let

$$\psi\circ\varphi^{-1}\left(x\right)=\left(\tilde x^1\left(x\right),\dots,\tilde x^n\left(x\right)\right)$$
in the middle of his exposition, despite each $\tilde x^i$ already standing for the component functions of $\psi$. In this case, it easily follows that

$$\left(\psi\circ\varphi^{-1}\right)_*\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial
x^i}\right|_{\varphi\left(p\right)}=\left.\frac{\partial\tilde
x^j}{\partial
x^i}\left(\varphi\left(p\right)\right)\frac{\partial}{\partial\tilde
x^j}\right|_{\psi\left(p\right)}.$$

If someone could confirm.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I meant.

Comment: @JackLee, thank you. I am enjoying your book so far; my mind is just not yet fully used to the mental gymnastics of graduate-level mathematics!